# UIDropSession, update "green +" system indicator

Tags: swift

I am currently developing a simple drag&drop application using iOS 11 apis: `UIDragInteractionDelegate` and `UIDropInteractionDelegate`

I success to lock the drop feature to my project only, however I did not find any solution to customize the green indicator appearing when a drop can be activated. My app will provide other form of indication.

[image: the green button]

I noticed in the `UIDropSession` the variable progressIndicatorStyle, but I don't see any change when updated

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    session.progressIndicatorStyle = .none
    return session.localDragSession != nil && session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self)
}
```

Has anyone succeeded in hiding this indicator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to fix the issue.

The indicator was generated by this function:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
}
```

If you want to remove this indicator, simply change the parameter to `.move`.